# The setting language of your computer is not compatible with this version of the code. please change the language to English

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have installed new software (sams2000) on my windows (10) computer and once I started launching it, I got the following error message:
`the setting language of your computer is not compatible with this version of the code. please change the language to English (United States)`
though I doubled checked my language settings and English is the default language on my PC, I don't why I still see this message. Screen shots of the message and my language settings are shown. I found similar topic [here](https://superuser.com/questions/302988/virus-the-version-of-this-file-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-windows-y) , but mine is different.

[image: This is the error message]

[image: These are my language settings]

Any suggestions are highly welcome

Comment: It appears that your computer is actually set for Arabic/Saudi Arabia - the notification icon is showing the number of notifications as a non-Western numeral, and the date is also shown using non-Western numerals. You may need to change the Region to United States instead of Saudi Arabia to successfully install the package; alternatively, contact the manufacturer of the package for additional support.

Comment: Your linked question has absolutely nothing to do with your question.  The message isn't even remotely the same message.  The message in question is being generated by the application, the message in the linked question, is being generted by Windows due to the application being incompatible with the user's version of Windows.  **Your issue is due to your computer's region.**

Comment: I have come across many products that check for the wrong setting in Windows. This one seems to be checking the region and thinking this is the language, so you must change to make it work.

Comment: I changed everything to English (Region, timezone, and **date & time format**) and got it successfully working. Later I changed the timezone back to Riyadh and working smoothly. Thanks to All who supported my case. I think one of you (@JeffZeitlin) should upgrade his comment as an answer to get some credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your computer is actually set for Arabic/Saudi Arabia - the notification icon is showing the number of notifications as a non-Western numeral, and the date is also shown using non-Western numerals. You may need to change the Region to United States instead of Saudi Arabia to successfully install the package; alternatively, contact the manufacturer of the package for additional support.

Changing the Region is more than the time zone; it also sets defaults for display language, keyboard layout, text-to-speech and speech recognition, handwriting recognition, and probably other things that I've not identified.  It is not clear from the error message *which* "setting language" was causing the installer to reject installation; I would strongly recommend contacting the manufacturer of the package for additional information regarding this.

Comment: I believe that the **date and time format** is mostly matter.